# Render PDF in python with stringIO

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt4

I want to write a pdf viewer in `python` using `PyQt4`. According to some of the answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562945/how-to-display-pdf-with-python-poppler-qt4), I am thinking to use `QtPoppler`. But it seems like `QtPoppler` requires a Pdf file stored on a disk. However, I have a pdf data in RAM (stringIO) and I don't want to write it on a disk. Is there any way to generate a pdf from stringIO?

Answer (score 1):

According to their docs, poppler-python closely follows the C++ `QtPoppler` API.

So you should be able to use [Poppler.Document.loadFromData](http://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt4/classPoppler_1_1Document.html#a4cb26b16fedbf13d31173dec47e96fb3) to do want you want. This takes the pdf file contents as a [QByteArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html), so you just need to make the appropriate conversion from your StringIO object.